# Freemarker if statements inside html elements

Tags: liferay, freemarker, velocity

I have some liferay templates I am attempting to convert from velocity to freemarker.

The old code had some if statements inside html elements. For example:

```
<a href="url" #if (condition) style="thisStyleOnlyIfcondition" #end> example </a>
```

Is it possible to have freemarker if statements in an html element? Like this?

```
<a href="url"
    <#if (condition)>
       style="thisStyleOnlyIfcondition"
    </#if>
>
  example
</a>
```

When I try writing that in video studio code it appears to have errors. I know that the issue is likely the <> characters being in html, but how would I avoid this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freemarker doesn't care for anything around its tags, so this is fine

Editors that try to make sense of both, HTML *and* the templating code (if only for syntax highlighting) are easy to confuse with such syntax that contains what looks like tags within tags.

You could generate a style value before the tag that always gets included, just either empty or with a value, to make the editor happy:

(Pseudocode - validate what works (e.g. for linebreaks), I'm not working with freemarker often. And there might be more elegant solutions)

```
<#assign conditionalStyle>
  <#if condition>
    thisStyleOnlyIfcondition
  </#if>
</#assign>

<a href="url" style="${conditionalStyle}">...</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! First it is good to know you can put the freemarker right in and it will work. I should have tested first before asking but the environment I am testing in isn't the easiest. Second, that is a good idea assigning it as a variable outside of the code. I may do it that way.